# Cryptic cross... with words

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, geography, cryptic-crosswords

Solve the clues and fit the answers into the grid.

> [image: cryptic cross]
>
> 1. Far north Silicon Valley's research & development leaders surround Jessica (8)
> 2. Pop star loses British-American distribution rights to music organization (4)
> 3. Kingdom's famous sherpa leaves greatest top, gets second award (6)
> 4. Clapton song loses heart, gets inside club to be McCartney song (6)
> 5. Yale professor Jenny with rights to Diablo north of Mali's capital (8)
> 6. In retrospect, Korean Secretary-General is a Swedish actress (5)
> 7. Before Christ, Jonah's insiders introduced first Hebrew God (6)
> 8. Excess of vitamins lacking irate vim leads to state of trance (8)
> 9. Metric cruise around psychic medium is funny business (6)
> 10. Flamboyant fly's wings around wish-granting body part (6)
> 11. Jovial monster rips out heart, surrounding first person (5)
> 12. Animated series presumed ending with vocal piece (5)
> 13. Clothing material shelled for Holy Roman emperor (4)
> 14. Taiwanese company contracted Nigerian people (3)
> 15. Ancient piano instrumental finishes grand finale (3)
> 16. Elizabeth places a wager close to fourth of July (5)
> 17. Tried architect glances, moves foot to the west (5)
> 18. Ethiopian opera featuring keyboard instrument (5)
> 19. Postal director to turn head with extreme envy (3)
> 20. Bold goer initially heads up inside rural centre (5)
> 21. Army unit with small four-wheeler and wizard (8)
> 22. Standards organization backs network model (3)
> 23. Boating tool from metallic mineral, reportedly (3)
> 24. 113 previously used underwater turtle heads (3)
> 25. Tea and baked goods for unsightly creatures (6)
> 26. Retailers can cover the large and the small (5)
> 27. Sumerian city falls, ending Sufi celebration (3)
> 28. Don't start to hide behind blue-green toxin (7)
> 29. Evil overlord central to dinosaur onslaught (6)
> 30. Heroic poem briefly does make up chapter (7)
> 31. Street goes below tree, never seen before (5)
> 32. Elizabeth initially next in line, loses turn (5)
> 33. Latin initialism is heartless Shinto deity (4)
> 34. African fly shirtless to dictator's second name (4)
> 35. Tool lineup featuring top Florida scorer (4)
> 36. Spice rings encircle half-hearted Ronald (7)
> 37. Programming pioneer's top three proverbs (3)
> 38. Deep blue crowdfunding site with no ego (6)
> 39. Foster to perish after Norwegian author (5)
> 40. Murderbot Ultra One ultimately scrapped (6)
> 41. Back balsam? Ah, a beautiful country (7)
> 42. Dwarf agent surrounds Dracula actor (6)
> 43. No start for the trip of me and you (3)
> 44. On the premises, part spins it up (2 4)
> 45. Legislative organs for storyteller (5)
> 46. Partial compounds in ghastly lager (6)
> 47. Māori prophet's revolutionary aura (3)
> 48. Saudi Arabia owns any Chinese city (5)
> 49. Avenge odd appliance manufacturer (3)
> 50. Vengeful seaman held in Allahabad (4)
> 51. Cold sea fog from an empty hangar (4)
> 52. Decapitated cat charged particle (3)
> 53. Biblical figure remains wingless (3)
> 54. Monagan brings up nineties host (6)
> 55. Visibly injure a feline villain (4)
> 56. Knighted actor secretly lesbian (3)
> 57. Champion checker in the house (3)
> 58. Bohemian northbound target (3)
> 59. No diaper, no happy couple (3)
> 60. Motor club's credit rating (3)
> 61. Brush a pet in living room (5)
> 62. Elevated bonus card game (3)
> 63. Gorilla secretly escapes (3)
> 64. Empty spaces for Roombas (7)
> 65. Eastern part of Eurasia (4)
> 66. Michael: a girl's name? (6)
> 67. Letter beta sans beta (3)
> 68. Beauty upsets kingdom (3)
> 69. Melted into Braxton (4)
> 70. Car with no sound (5)
> 71. To sweeten honey (5)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the final grid (credit to Jacob Shetler, Remi Henry and M Oehm for solving some of the clues)

> [image]

**1.** Far north Silicon Valley's research & development leaders surround Jessica (8)

> Svalbard = Alba inside S.V.R & D

**2.** Pop star loses British-American distribution rights to music organization (4)

> Riaa = Rihanna - hnn

**3.** Kingdom's famous sherpa leaves greatest top, gets second award (6)

> Norway (found by Jacob Shetler)

**4.** Clapton song loses heart, gets inside club to be McCartney song (6)

> Lalula = La(y)la + c**lu**b

**5.** Yale professor Jenny with rights to Diablo north of Mali's capital (8)

> Lindblom = Lind + blo + M

**6.** In retrospect, Korean Secretary-General is a Swedish actress (5)

> Noomi = The end of Ban Ki-moon spelled backwards

**7.** Before Christ, Jonah's insiders introduced first Hebrew God (6)

> Adonai = AD + ona + i

**8.** Excess of vitamins lacking irate vim leads to state of trance (8)

> Hypnosis = Hypervitaminosis without *irate vim*

**9.** Metric cruise around psychic medium is funny business (6)

> Sitcom = SI + T(c)om, where c is the middle of psychic (solved by M Oehm)

**10.** Flamboyant fly's wings around wish-granting body part (6)

> Flashy = f + lash + y

**11.** Jovial monster rips out heart, surrounding first person (5)

> Happy = Harpy - r + **p**erson (thanks to M Oehm)

**12.** Animated series presumed ending with vocal piece (5)

> Daria (found by Jacob Shetler)

**13.** Clothing material shelled for Holy Roman emperor (4)

> Otto = (C)otto(n)

**14.** Taiwanese company contracted Nigerian people (3)

> Asu = Asus - s

**15.** Ancient piano instrumental finishes grand finale (3)

> Old = pian**o** instrumenta**l** + gran**d**

**16.** Elizabeth places a wager close to fourth of July (5)

> Betsy = Bets + y

**17.** Tried architect glances, moves foot to the west (5)

> Speer = peers with s on the left.

**18.** Ethiopian opera featuring keyboard instrument (5)

> Piano = Ethio**pian o**pera

**19.** Postal director to turn head with extreme envy (3)

> Uwe = t**u**rn + **w**ith + **e**nvy

**20.** Bold goer initially heads up inside rural centre (5)

> Uhura = **h**eads **u**p inside 'ura'

**21.** Army unit with small four-wheeler and wizard (8)

> Squadron = s + quad + ron

**22.** Standards organization backs network model (3)

> OSI = ISO backwards

**23.** Boating tool from metallic mineral, reportedly (3)

> Oar = sounds like ore

**24.** 113 previously used underwater turtle heads (3)

> Uut = **u**sed **u**nderwater **t**urtle

**25.** Tea and baked goods for unsightly creatures (6)

> Trolls = T + rolls

**26.** Retailers can cover the large and the small (5)

> Lidls = Lid + L + S

**27.** Sumerian city falls, ending Sufi celebration (3)

> Urs = Ur + fall**s**

**28.** Don't start to hide behind blue-green toxin (7)

> Cyanide = Cyan + (h)ide

**29.** Evil overlord central to dinosaur onslaught (6)

> Sauron (found by Remi Henry)

**30.** Heroic poem briefly does make up chapter (7)

> Episode = Epi(c) + anagram of *does*

**31.** Street goes below tree, never seen before (5)

> First = Fir + st

**32.** Elizabeth initially next in line, loses turn (5)

> Queen = Queue - U(-turn) + **n**ext (thanks M Oehm)

**33.** Latin initialism is heartless Shinto deity (4)

> Inri = In(a)ri (thanks M Oehm)

**34.** African fly shirtless to dictator's second name (4)

> Sese = Tsetse without the Ts

**35.** Tool lineup featuring top Florida scorer (4)

> Olli = To**ol li**neup

**36.** Spice rings encircle half-hearted Ronald (7)

> Oregano = O + regan + o

**37.** Programming pioneer's top three proverbs (3)

> Ada = **Ada**ges (thanks M Oehm)

**38.** Deep blue crowdfunding site with no ego (6)

> Indigo = Indiegogo - ego

**39.** Foster to perish after Norwegian author (5)

> Jodie = Jo + die

**40.** Murderbot Ultra One ultimately scrapped (6)

> Ultron = Ultr(a) + On(e)

**41.** Back balsam? Ah, a beautiful country (7)

> Bahamas = bal**sam? Ah, a b**eautiful

**42.** Dwarf agent surrounds Dracula actor (6)

> Sleepy = s(lee)py

**43.** No start for the trip of me and you (3)

> Our = (T)our

**44.** On the premises, part spins it up (2 4)

> In situ = sp**ins it u**p

**45.** Legislative organs for storyteller (5)

> Dumas = Duma is the lower chamber of the Russian parliament.

**46.** Partial compounds in ghastly lager (6)

> Singha = compound**s in gha**stly

**47.** Māori prophet's revolutionary aura (3)

> Rua = **aur**a backwards

**48.** Saudi Arabia owns any Chinese city (5)

> Sanya = S**any**A

**49.** Avenge odd appliance manufacturer (3)

> AEG = **A**v**e**n**g**e

**50.** Vengeful seaman held in Allahabad (4)

> Ahab = All**ahab**ad

**51.** Cold sea fog from an empty hangar (4)

> Haar = ha(ng)ar

**52.** Decapitated cat charged particle (3)

> Ion (found by Jacob Shetler)

**53.** Biblical figure remains wingless (3)

> Eli = (R)eli(c) (figured out by M Oehm)

**54.** Monagan brings up nineties host (6)

> Nagano = M**onagan** backwards

**55.** Visibly injure a feline villain (4)

> Scar (found by Remi Henry)

**56.** Knighted actor secretly lesbian (3)

> Ian = lesb**ian** (credit to M Oehm)

**57.** Champion checker in the house (3)

> Hou = **hou**se

**58.** Bohemian northbound target (3)

> Aim = Bohe**mia**n reversed.

**59.** No diaper, no happy couple (3)

> Nay = a brand of baby clothes and also **n**o + h**a**pp**y**

**60.** Motor club's credit rating (3)

> AAA = both an American motor club and bond credit rating

**61.** Brush a pet in living room (5)

> Groom = livin**g room**

**62.** Elevated bonus card game (3)

> Uno = b**onu**s

**63.** Gorilla secretly escapes (3)

> Ape = esc**ape**s

**64.** Empty spaces for Roombas (7)

> Vacuums = although vacua is usually the plural

**65.** Eastern part of Eurasia (4)

> Asia (found by Remi Henry)

**66.** Michael: a girl's name? (6)

> Jordan = Michael Jordan (basketballer) or Jordan (Katie Price)

**67.** Letter beta sans beta (3)

> Eta (found by Remi Henry)

**68.** Beauty upsets kingdom (3)

> UAE = B**eau**ty mixed up (credit to M Oehm)

**69.** Melted into Braxton (4)

> Toni = anagram of *into*

**70.** Car with no sound (5)

> Audio = Audi + o

**71.** To sweeten honey (5)

> Sugar = meaning to sweeten and is synonymous with honey as an informal address.

Comment: Phew, well done! (I think 68 and 56 are missing a hidden-answer indicators. The missing wings in 53 are R and C. The singular of 45 is the lower chamber of the Russian parliament. The Cruise in 9 should be capital, because it's SI + "medium" letter of psychic in Tom. The female monster's ripped-out heart in 11 is an R.)

Comment: @MOehm Thank you. I've filled those in now. There are still a few missing so I'm not sure that the grid is 100% correct but I think only maybe 3 or 4 letters could be wrong.

Comment: Ah, I was looking for the question marks. I think the grid and the unexplained answers look good. For what it's worth: 32: The lost turn is a U turn, missing from queue and getting an E from Liz in return. 33: The Shinto deity is Inari. 37: The "top three proverbs" are ADE(ge). 47: The [prophet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rua_Kenana_Hepetipa) is hidden backwards, again without indicator. I think 60, 68 and 77 are just double defs.

Comment: @MOehm Ahh my bad, it looks like I've been pretty consistently failing to indicate the "hidden" clues when the thing that's hidden is to be read backwards... I'll try to keep it in mind in the future.

Comment: Only 27 and 34 are incorrect. Note that I modified 34 to fix a part-of-speech error...

Comment: @jafe, thank you for the clarification, I've updated the grid - still unsure about the unsolved clues.

Comment: @MOehm 32 still doesn't make full sense to me, we still need to pick up an 'n' from somewhere.

Comment: Yes, that's because I botched the explanation. It's N (initially next) in QUE(u)E. Def. is Elizabeth, but that doesn't explain why the N comes at the end -- "in" suggests that the N should be surrounded by the letters of QUEE.

Comment: @MOehm Ah yes, that makes more sense, thank you.

Comment: @jafe, I think we've got them all now.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Well done!

Answer (score 9):

Partial Answer :

29. Evil overlord central to dinosaur onslaught (6)

> dino**saur** **on**slaught = SAURON

55. Visibly injure a feline villain (4)

> SCAR (villain from the lion king)

65. Eastern part of Eurasia (4)

> EUR**ASIA** = ASIA

66. Michael: a girl's name? (6)

> **Mich**a**el** = Michel

67. Letter beta sans beta (3)

> BETA - B = ETA

Answer (score 8):

Partial Answer

3. Kingdom's famous sherpa leaves greatest top, gets second award (6)

> NORWAY – **Norgay** minus **g** plus **w**

12. Animated series presumed ending with vocal piece (5)

> DARIA - **D** plus **Aria**

27. Sumerian city falls, ending Sufi celebration (3)

> URN - City of **Ur** plus **n**

52. Decapitated cat charged particle (3)

> ION - **CATION** minus **CAT**